# Vendor recommendation engine

Tags: java, apache, mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I am working on portal where I have `PO` with details of ordered `items` and `Vendor` we are going to deal with.

I am trying to make a `item based Vendor recommendation engine` for the next quotation so that `buyer` can have idea before dealing.

Right now I have `Vendor`, `Item` and few `Parameters` to evaluate as mentioned below,

- How much quantity he sent on every order? For example, ordered 100 but delivered only 80
- How is the quality of item? Any damage? For example, 20 damage from ordered 100.
- What is the actual delivery date based on expected delivery date? For example, expecting 26th May but receiving item on 28th May.
- and few others will be added in future.

And all the parameters have some sort of importance and result comes out of 100%.

I came to know about recommendation feature of `Apache Mahout`.

https://mahout.apache.org/users/recommender/recommender-documentation.html

I have few questions mentioned below :

1. Does `Apache Mahout` provides recommendation on multiple parameter?
2. How we can deal with this situation? Guidance please.
3. Is `Apache Mahout` right choice for this kind of situation? Any other option?
4. Is this content based or collaborative filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, formula and complexity is very high.

So, I don't find Mahout as right choice. Then, I have decided to use the PostgreSQL database and application is running fine without any problem on production.

Comment: @SO users, please add your answer if you still have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The page you reference is for the old style mapreduce recommenders that are being deprecated. See this page for newer tech https://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/recommender-overview.html

Mahout can create the model for recommenders but you need a whole system of data input processing and serving. We have an end-to-end solution built on Apache PredictionIO that uses the Mahout code above but wraps it in all the other services you will need.

The Universal Recommender here: http://actionml.com/universal-recommender

Comment: Thanks, In my case, is it collaborative filtering or content based filtering? I am new to Machine Learning.